# Custom Monthly Billing for Stripe Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I have to try to look for a custom monthly billing for stripe but not able to find one. Can someone please help me implement this for stripe Laravel?

Basically, I have an inventory business and I want to charge clients monthly according to the space they are taking in my warehouse.

So like when they sign up is charge is $3.75 times the number of ftes they order to be fulfilled with us, plus $12 times the total volume of their order. The volume would be calculated by the number of each ftes times each of their volumes. (Volume is In cubic feet)

So if they order fulfillment for 50 T-Shirts, and the volume of each T-Shirt is .5 feet. Then the fee is 3.75 * 50 + 12 * 50 *.5

How can I do that in Stripe monthly subscription? Because it only gives me the option to create a plan but I am not able to put these calculations in that plan. If you think there is some better way to implement it by using some other library please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Stripe's metered billing feature](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing):

> With metered billing, you charge your customers based on their consumption of your service during the billing cycle, instead of explicitly setting quantities. For example, if you run an email SaaS business, you can record how many emails your customers send per month, then bill them for the total number at the end of the month.
>
> Like other subscription models, metered billing is defined by the [prices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create) you create for your product or service. You must also [record usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create), and you can customize how to handle usage records.

Comment: Thank you for you kind response. Can we do the same with Paypal too?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with PayPal's subscription capabilities.

Comment: okay sir thank you